# How to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python

Tags: python, string

Is there an easy way to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python?

So for:

```
a = 'ZENOVW'
```

I would like to return:

```
'ENOVWZ'
```

Answer (score 381, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> a = 'ZENOVW'
>>> ''.join(sorted(a))
'ENOVWZ'
```

Comment: Note that `sorted(a)` will return a sorted list, so for string comparisons you don't need to `join()` (see askewchan answer's below).

Comment: Note that `''.join(sorted(a, reverse=True, key=str.lower))` can be used to perform a reversed case-insensitive sort. Could be handy.

Answer (score 114):

```
>>> a = 'ZENOVW'
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> print(b)
['E', 'N', 'O', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
```

`sorted` returns a list, so you can make it a string again using `join`:

```
>>> c = ''.join(b)
```

which joins the items of `b` together with an empty string `''` in between each item.

```
>>> print(c)
'ENOVWZ'
```

Answer (score 41):

Sorted() solution can give you some unexpected results with other strings.

List of other solutions:

### Sort letters and make them distinct:

```
>>> s = "Bubble Bobble"
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(s.lower())))
' belou'
```

### Sort letters and make them distinct while keeping caps:

```
>>> s = "Bubble Bobble"
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(s)))
' Bbelou'
```

### Sort letters and keep duplicates:

```
>>> s = "Bubble Bobble"
>>> ''.join(sorted(s))
' BBbbbbeellou'
```

If you want to get rid of the space in the result, add strip() function in any of those mentioned cases:

```
>>> s = "Bubble Bobble"
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(s.lower()))).strip()
'belou'
```

Comment: Hey, that first solution was kinda useful for a piece of homework in which I had to find a letter using bisection. Yes, I already know about the string class and the find() method, but this defeats the purpose of the exercise ;)

Answer (score 13):

Python function`sorted` returns ASCII based result for string.

**INCORRECT**: In the example below, `e` and `d` is behind `H` and `W` due it's to ASCII value.

```
>>>a = "Hello World!"
>>>"".join(sorted(a))
' !!HWdellloor'
```

**CORRECT**: In order to write the sorted string *without* changing the case of letter. Use the code:

```
>>> a = "Hello World!"
>>> "".join(sorted(a,key=lambda x:x.lower()))
' !deHllloorW'

OR (Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

>>> a = "Hello World!"
>>> "".join(sorted(a,key=str.lower))
' !deHllloorW'
```

If you want to remove all punctuation and numbers.
Use the code:

```
>>> a = "Hello World!"
>>> "".join(filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(), sorted(a,key=lambda x:x.lower())))
'deHllloorW'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = 'ZENOVW'
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, sorted(a))
'ENOVWZ'
```

Comment: `reduce` needs to be imported  `from functools import reduce` which makes it awkward

Answer (score 2):

the code can be used to sort string in alphabetical order without using any inbuilt function of python

k = input("Enter any string again ")

```
li = []
x = len(k)
for i in range (0,x):
    li.append(k[i])

print("List is : ",li)


for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,x):
        if li[i]<li[j]:
            temp = li[i]
            li[i]=li[j]
            li[j]=temp
j=""

for i in range(0,x):
    j = j+li[i]

print("After sorting String is : ",j)
```

Comment: Ideally you want to add some explanation to the code to make clear what it does. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Really liked the answer with the reduce() function. Here's another way to sort the string using accumulate().

```
from itertools import accumulate
s = 'mississippi'
print(tuple(accumulate(sorted(s)))[-1])
```

sorted(s) -> ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'm', 'p', 'p', 's', 's', 's', 's']

tuple(accumulate(sorted(s)) -> ('i', 'ii', 'iii', 'iiii', 'iiiim', 'iiiimp', 'iiiimpp', 'iiiimpps', 'iiiimppss', 'iiiimppsss', 'iiiimppssss')

We are selecting the last index (-1) of the tuple

Comment: Well done for your first answer. Just consider a string of 1 million characters, your tuple() command will create a huge list of accumulated options which uses unnecessarily large amount of memory.

Comment: Agreed. So, to improve space complexity, the idea is to work with the iterable itself, instaed of converting it to a data structure. Nice. Thank You.