# reorder characters in a string in Python

Tags: python

Wondering if there is a simple way to reorder characters in a string in alphabet order?

Saying, if "hello", want it to be "ehllo"? Tried sort method does not exist. If anyone have any great ideas, it will be great.

```
a = 'hello'
print a.sort()
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: `print ''join.sorted('hello')`

Comment: @RNar, wondering how ''join.sorted('hello') happened underlying? Seems magic. :)

Comment: look at the link. it makes use of `str.join(list)` and `sorted(iterable)` methods

Comment: BTW, shall I import some packages in order to use join? I am using Python 2.7.x.

Comment: no those are both built in methods

Comment: @RNar, it is very smart. Could you help to add an answer? I will mark it as answer to benefit other people. Have a good weekend. :)

Comment: I think the first comment had a typo and was supposed to be `print(''.join(sorted("hello")))`

Comment: @Galax, yes, that is my bad. because it is python 2, the out most brackets are not necessary but the call to join should be in brackets

Comment: Yes the outer brackets are not needed for Python 2, I didn't see any mention of the Python version though. The typo was the `.` in the wrong place and the missing brackets after `join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = 'hello'
a = ''.join(sorted(a))
print a
```

It should return 'ehllo'.

Here's a similar post about the same problem:
[How to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046242/how-to-sort-the-letters-in-a-string-alphabetically-in-python)

Comment: Thanks user1159580, smart answer!

Comment: @LinMa: if it helped you, could you accept it?

Comment: @jermenkoo, good question, will definitely accept. Done. :)

Comment: Thanks Brian! Mark as answered and have a good weekend.