# Sorting characters of a string in Python

Tags: python, sorting

How to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python without using join()? Using join() we can do this:

```
def sort_string(a)
    return ''.join(sorted(a))
```

Is there a way to sort string without using join()?

Comment: You can perform the join manually one letter at a time, but why wouldn't you want to use `join`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046242/how-to-sort-the-letters-in-a-string-alphabetically-in-python)

Comment: @binarysubstrate that gives the answer he starts with.  Of course, I agree with interjay: why don't you want to use join?  That is a very pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because use `str.join` here is the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct as strings are immutable in python. So, it's impossible to change (in your case - sort) an existing string. You have to create new one (you do it with join() call).

Also, good notes about sorting letters in string in python can be found here: [How to sort the letters in a string alphabetically in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046242/how-to-sort-the-letters-in-a-string-alphabetically-in-python)