# How to avoid redundancy and apply filter into string combination

Tags: python, algorithm, python-itertools

I would like to avoid redundancy into all possible combinations in a list of string (for example `1122` is the same thing as `2211` in my context therefore only one or the other should be in the resulted list).

I would also like to apply a filter during the combination. For example, I don't want to have any string in the result that contains `3`.

How should I handle this logic?

This code is doing the combination

```
>>> keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(['11', '22', '33'], repeat = 2)]
>>> keywords
['1111', '1122', '1133', '2211', '2222', '2233', '3311', '3322', '3333']
```

Comment: should `2222` and `3333` also be skipped?

Comment: Maybe loop and sort each string, add original string if sorted string doesn't exist in new list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046242/how-to-sort-the-letters-in-a-string-alphabetically-in-python  I can write up a better answer if this looks like it's the right direction you want to go.

Comment: any string that contains a 3 should be dropped

Comment: If you don't want 3 in the output you should filter such strings out of the _input_ to `product`.

Comment: Will `repeat` always be 2?

Comment: yes always two - I cannot filter from the `input` because this is a toy example, in my project, I am actually working with a pandas data frame and the filter criteria are much more complex and involve calculation between each element of the combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your actual data there *may* be a more efficient way to do this, but the algorithm below will work. We eliminate the duplicates by a simple comparison. I've put the check for '3's into a function. That's slightly slower than doing it directly in the list comprehension, but it makes the code more general.

```
import itertools

bases = ['11', '22', '33', '44']

def is_ok(u, v):
    ''' Test if a u,v pair is permitted '''
    return not ('3' in u or '3' in v)

keywords = [u+v for u, v in itertools.product(bases, repeat = 2) if u <= v and is_ok(u, v)]
```

**output**

```
['1111', '1122', '1144', '2222', '2244', '4444']
print(keywords)
```

Answer (score 2):

The same is possible by filtering `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


bases = ["11", "22", "33", "44"]

[x+y for x,y in it.combinations_with_replacement(bases, 2) if "3" not in x+y]
# ['1111', '1122', '1144', '2222', '2244', '4444']
```

This version is more general and does not rely on comparing numeric strings.

---

**Details**

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) we can understand why this works:

> The code for `combinations_with_replacement()` can be also expressed as a subsequence of `product()` after filtering entries where the elements are not in sorted order (according to their position in the input pool)

```
def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    for indices in product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if sorted(indices) == list(indices):
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

In this manner, each item is associated with a unique index.  When the indices of two items are compared, only sorted combinations are used to yield an item.  The remaining indices are discarded as already seen.

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)                                         # discarded
(1, 1)
...
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) for more details on the similarity between this tool and `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
import itertools

def main():

    newkeywords = []
    keywords = ["".join(i) for i in itertools.product(["11", "22", "33"], repeat = 2)]
    for item in keywords:
        newitem = "".join(sorted(item))
        if "3" not in newitem and newitem not in newkeywords:
            newkeywords.append(newitem)
    print(newkeywords)

main()
```

results:

```
['1111', '1122', '2222']
```

It makes a new list, and if that sorted item (which makes 1122 the same as 2211) exists or the number "3" exists, don't add it to the new list.